# Accessing python httplib2 over a network share in windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, httplib2

I am trying to run python from a network share on windows 7.
The network share is T:

```
>t:\python-2.6.1\python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67517, Dec  4 2008, 16:51:00) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
httplib2\__init__.py:29: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
import md5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\python2.6\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
import httplib
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\httplib.py", line 77, in <module>
import mimetools
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\random.py", line 871, in <module>
_inst = Random()
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\random.py", line 96, in __init__
self.seed(x)
File "T:\python-2.6.1\lib\random.py", line 110, in seed
a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

When I copy python-2.6.1 to my local drive it works fine. It also works fine on my windows XP machine using the same network share.

Comment: The specific error certainly looks unexpected, but can you check whether the latest httplib2 gives you the same problem?  The fact you're getting the md5 deprecation warning suggests you're on an older version.  Maybe it will help (but probably not).

Answer (score 1):

Peter, 
When I copy python-2.6.1 from the network share to my local drive it works fine. It also works fine on my windows XP machine using the same network share.

Comment: okay the problem is not with httplib2 but with random. 
If I do import random at the prompt it throws the above error.
All works fine if I copy python to my local drive.